# Rollback and Update depending on the changeLog File entries

Tags: git, jenkins, liquibase

Currently I have a jenkins server that will have multiple nodes. In each node I have a database running to support tests in that specific node.
I also build different feature branchs in all the nodes.

This environment have a caveat that is the database. Different branches can have different versions of the database, and unfortunately I cannot drop and create the full database per build. So I need to use update and rollback from liquibase.

Currently I have liquibase inside my maven compile cycle so it work automatically. But I need to be able to update and rollback the changes based on the current file.

The current behavior only allow me to update when new changesets are present.

Example:

> branch master have changeset B,C,D
>
> branch F1 have changeset B,C,D,E
>
> branch F2 have changeset B,C,D
>
> I run task for F1 and the changeset E is added to the database. After
>   if I run branch F2 I need it to rollback to changeset D, but update do
>   not allow me to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One thing that we do for tests like this is use Liquibase's dropAll functionality. It is faster than completely dropping and re-creating a database, but accompishes many of the same goals - to have a clean empty database that you can then use Liquibase update to create the schema, and then do tests against that.

There is a maven plugin task that does this. http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/maven/maven_dropall.html

Comment: I understand that, and that was my first option, but I need to do one import of a 2GB file into the database each time I create it, so that is not really one options :s